# "ORDER BY CASE..." causing Invalid expression in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, firebird, firebird2.5

Can anyone point out what is causing me to get the

> Invalid expression in the ORDER BY clause (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

error on the following query?  This is in Firebird 2.5.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total,
        CASE WHEN YR BETWEEN 1990 AND 1995 THEN '1990-1995' 
             WHEN YR BETWEEN 1996 AND 2000 THEN '1996-2000'
             WHEN YR BETWEEN 2001 AND 2005 THEN '2001-2005'
             ELSE '2005-2017' END AS vehicle_year
FROM bb_history
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YR BETWEEN 1990 AND 1995 THEN 1
              WHEN YR BETWEEN 1996 AND 2000 THEN 2
              WHEN YR BETWEEN 2001 AND 2005 THEN 3
              ELSE 4 END
```

Comment: there is no `yr` column after grouping. Either include yr in the select or modify your order by

Comment: `order by 2` should be ok as of now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `YR` column in `order by` because it is not part of the result of grouping. It seems you just want to order by the generated `vehicle_year` column, so you can just order by that (or by 2):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total,
        CASE WHEN YR BETWEEN 1990 AND 1995 THEN '1990-1995' 
             WHEN YR BETWEEN 1996 AND 2000 THEN '1996-2000'
             WHEN YR BETWEEN 2001 AND 2005 THEN '2001-2005'
             ELSE '2005-2017' END AS vehicle_year
FROM bb_history
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY vehicle_year;
```

Comment: Implementation-wise it is likely that it is already sorted without the `order by` (just don't depend on it).

Answer (score -2):

You have only two selected column why you added '3' and '4', but here is the query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total,
        CASE WHEN YR BETWEEN 1990 AND 1995 THEN '1990-1995' 
             WHEN YR BETWEEN 1996 AND 2000 THEN '1996-2000'
             WHEN YR BETWEEN 2001 AND 2005 THEN '2001-2005'
             ELSE '2005-2017' END AS vehicle_year
FROM bb_history
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY CASE WHEN vehicle_year BETWEEN 1990 AND 1995 THEN 1
              WHEN vehicle_year BETWEEN 1996 AND 2000 THEN 2
              WHEN vehicle_year BETWEEN 2001 AND 2005 THEN 3
              ELSE 4 END
```

Comment: The case won't order by column index, but by the **value** 1, 2, 3 or 4.